# custom date picker in ios

Tags: ios, datepicker, uidatepicker, ipad

Im developing a app for iPad. The requirement of this app is to show a date picker having day + month + time + year.

`UIDatePicker` doesn't have this option. It only has Date & Time or Date or Time.

```
UIDatePicker *dtPicker  = [UIDatePicker alloc] init];
dtPicker.mode = UIDatePickerMode - UIDatePickerModeTime /     UIDatePickerModeDate / UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime
```

Is there any picker with all three combined?

Answer (score 3):

No way to do this using [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html).

**Suggestion:**

You can use a Customized [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) to do this.

Create a picker with 4 fields and manipulate them with 4 arrays with corresponding values.
(You need to do the validating stuffs and other things)

Comment: it will be too diff to handle it :(

Comment: @cancerian: Yes, but there is no other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to customize your data picker: [IXPickerOverlayView](https://github.com/Inexika/Inexika-Custom-Controls)

In github repo you can find example, sources and resources.